# Importance of papers quality for postdoc positions

Tags: publications, postdocs

I am currently on the edge of defending my viva and receiving a doctorate in foreign language teaching & learning. Teacher-researcher publish usually in Q2-Q3 journals mostly and very occasionally in Q1 journals. What are the chances of me landing a postdoc in a university abroad (out of Algeria) with papers in Q2 journals? It is essential to publish in Q1 journals?

Comment: The title of your question asks about paper quality, but the body of your question actually asks about journal rankings. These are two different things. Which of the two do you actually want to ask about?

Comment: What are you considering as a Q1,2,3,4 journal? The idea of people in a particular field publishing in a particular quartile "very occasionally" doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @BryanKrause I believe "teacher-researcher" refers to OP's local surroundings: lab or institution. Then it all makes sense, at least as a social phenomenon: there are places - plenty of them! - with entrenched beliefs centered around the journal rankings. Say, "never submit to Q1 because it will be rejected anyway" or "Q2 is where we usually publish".

Comment: @Lodinn A teacher-researcher sounds to me like a general description of the kind of people most often doing education research world wide.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking at the issue too narrowly. Yes, paper quality is important because you need to impress some PI that it is worth taking you on (and paying you). But your past work is only part of the equation. Someone hard to work with is going to have a difficult time in any postdoc and possibly in obtaining one.

And balancing more vs better papers is an individual decision that a PI will make. Don't overthink it.

How much "work in progress" you can point to is probably a factor. How well you fit into an existing research program matters. What fresh ideas you might have. Lots of things.